# How can I show a specific part of an image when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a login page: on the right side there's the login form, while on the left side I have a simple image in a div.

It works fine when the window is full screen. When I resize the window, the div containing the image is resized correctly (50%) but right side of the image is shown. I prefer instead to see preferentially the left side of image.

Any solution to that?

```css
#logoindex {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoindex">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes for transform. https://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: What does your code snippet do?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can often be resolved by making the image a background. Here I'm setting background-position to keep it on the correct side.

```css
#logoindex {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-box {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400x100");
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div id="logoindex">
  <div class="img-box"></div>
</div>
```